# Does Spark SQL optimize lower() on both sides?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, catalyst-optimizer

Say I have this pseudo code in Spark SQL where t1 is a temp view built off of partitioned parquet files in HDFS and t2 is a small lookup file to filter the said temp view

```
select t1.* 
from t1
where exists(select * 
             from t2 
             where t1.id=t2.id and 
                   lower(t1.col) like lower(t2.pattern))  --to mimic ilike functionality
```

Will the optimizer treat `lower(t1.col) like lower(t2.pattern)` as case insensitive match? Or will it run transformations on these columns before performing the match?

I don't have access to the DAG to see what exactly happens behind the scenes so I am asking here to see if this is a known/documented optimization trick.

Comment: I didn't quite understand your question, are you asking if spark will tranform these 2 columns into lower, or it will not and will do a non-case-senstive comparision between the 2, right ?

Comment: @AbdennacerLachiheb Exactly!

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reproduce that case using scala and then I called explain() to get the physical plan (I'm pretty sure sql and scala will have the same physical plan because behind the scene it's the same optimizer named “Catalyst”)

```
import spark.implicits._
val df1 = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(("Car", "car"), ("bike", "Rocket"), ("Bus", "BUS"), ("Auto", "Machine") )).toDF("c1", "c2")
df1.filter(lower(col("c1")).equalTo(lower(col("c2")))).explain()

== Physical Plan ==
*(1) Project [_1#3 AS c1#8, _2#4 AS c2#9]
+- *(1) Filter ((isnotnull(_1#3) AND isnotnull(_2#4)) AND (lower(_1#3) = lower(_2#4)))
   +- *(1) SerializeFromObject [staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, knownnotnull(assertnotnull(input[0, scala.Tuple2, true]))._1, true, false, true) AS _1#3, staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, knownnotnull(assertnotnull(input[0, scala.Tuple2, true]))._2, true, false, true) AS _2#4]
      +- Scan[obj#2]
```

As you can see in the logical plan it will call lower each time to compare the 2 values: **lower(_1#3) = lower(_2#4)**.

Btw I tried same thing joining 2 dataframe, then filtering on lower but I got the same result.

I hope this answer your question.

Comment: Thanks for reproducing the scenario. I was seeing the same in my execution plan. I don't know how much of performance penalty I am paying for the `lower()`, but it looks like they just added support for `ilike` in Spark 3.3.0 https://spark.apache.org/releases/spark-release-3-3-0.html. I might as well push for an upgrade